# Make vertical Scrollbar visible keeping table header static

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table that is built with div tags (not html table tag), I'm trying to make the table scrollable horizontally and vertically keeping the header static.

I'm able to do that except that the vertical scrollbar is visible only when the horizontal scrollbar is scrolled till the end.

Can anyone help me fix this please ?

Here's a sample [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zp6n0zr2/16/) I've created. That is a rough fiddle I've created for posting here, Apologies for the bad styling.

**Html :**

```
<div class="query-grid-container">
<div class="table-container">
  <div class="list-container">
    <div style="width: 2000px;">
      <div class="header-cell" style="width: 250px;">
        <div class="cell-wrapper">
          <div class="sort" role="Button" tabindex="0">
            <span class="column-name">Detected Data Classification Type</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="header-cell" style="width: 250px;">
        <div class="cell-wrapper">
          <div class="sort" role="Button" tabindex="0">
            <span class="column-name">Asset Name</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="header-cell" style="width: 250px;">
        <div class="cell-wrapper">
          <div class="sort" role="Button" tabindex="0">
            <span class="column-name">Selected Data Classifications</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="header-cell" style="width: 250px;">
        <div class="cell-wrapper">
          <div class="sort" role="Button" tabindex="0">
            <span class="column-name">Detected Data Classifications</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="header-cell" style="width: 250px;">
        <div class="cell-wrapper">
          <div class="sort" role="Button" tabindex="0">
            <span class="column-name">Short Description</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="header-cell" style="width: 250px;">
        <div class="cell-wrapper">
          <div class="sort" role="Button" tabindex="0">
            <span class="column-name">someTitle0</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="header-cell" style="width: 250px;">
        <div class="cell-wrapper">
          <div class="sort" role="Button" tabindex="0">
            <span class="column-name">someTitle1</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="header-cell" style="width: 250px;">
        <div class="cell-wrapper">
          <div class="sort" role="Button" tabindex="0">
            <span class="column-name">someTitle2</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rows-container" style="width: 2000px;">
      <div class="row" tabindex="0" role="row">
        <div class="cell-group">
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[Inferred]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">
              <div>
                <a href="#">Account Number</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">
              <div>
                <a href="#">ACCOUNT_ID</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[ACCOUNT_ID, ACCOUNT_ID]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">A value representing an Account Number.</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" tabindex="0" role="row">
        <div class="cell-group">
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">
              <div>
                <a href="#">Address Line 3</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">Address Line 3 of a multi-line address.</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" tabindex="0" role="row">
        <div class="cell-group">
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">
              <div>
                <a href="#">Address Line 1</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">Address Line 1 of a multi-line address.</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" tabindex="0" role="row">
        <div class="cell-group">
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">
              <div>
                <a href="#">Address Line 2</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">Address Line 2 of a multi-line address.</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" tabindex="0" role="row">
        <div class="cell-group">
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">
              <div>
                <a href="#">Airport Code</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">A string representing the IATA airport code.</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" tabindex="0" role="row">
        <div class="cell-group">
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">
              <div>
                <a href="#">Alabama State Driver's License</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">A string representing driver license of US state Alabama.</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" tabindex="0" role="row">
        <div class="cell-group">
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">
              <div>
                <a href="#">Alaska State Driver's License</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">A seven digits number representing driver license of US state Alaska.</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" tabindex="0" role="row">
        <div class="cell-group">
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">
              <div>
                <a href="#">Alberta Province Driver's License</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">A string representing driver license of Canadian province Alberta.</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" tabindex="0" role="row">
        <div class="cell-group">
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">
              <div>
                <a href="#">American Express Card</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">A 16-18 character number that identifies an American Express credit card account.</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" tabindex="0" role="row">
        <div class="cell-group">
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">
              <div>
                <a href="#">Arizona State Driver's License</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">A string representing driver license of US state Arizona.</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.query-grid-container {
  height: calc(100% - 160px);
  margin: 48px 68px 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 136px);
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.loader-container {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.search-table-container {
  height: 100%;
}

.table-container {
  height: calc(100% - 72px);
}

.top-container {
  padding: 14px 30px 15px;
  background: color("white");
}

.result-title {
  color: color("blue", 80);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.result-sub-title {
  color: color("gray", 60);
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.no-result-title {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.no-result-container {
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  padding-top: 24px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: color("white");
}

.no-result-text {
  margin-top: 6px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.no-result-top-container {
  border-bottom: 1px solid color("gray", 10);
  padding: 14px 30px;
  background: color("white");
}

.name-header {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.query-description-container {
  margin: 10px 0 14px 0;
  padding-left: 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
}

.cell-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: normal;
  padding: 6px 0 10px 10px;
}

.table-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  background-color: color('white');
}

.list-container {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.rows-container {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.header-cell {
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 1px solid color("grey", 10);
  border-bottom: 2px solid color("grey", 10);
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position: relative;
}

.cell-wrapper {
  padding: 15px 0 9px;
  line-height: 24px;
  display: flex;
}

.checkbox-wrapper {
  margin-left: 38px;
  display: flex;
}

.column-name {
  color: color("blue", 80);
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: auto 6px auto 0;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

.sort {
  display: flex;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 0 0 0 2px;
}
.sort.sort-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sort.sort-btn:hover {
  background-color: color("gray", 10, 0.2);
}
.sort .sort-icon {
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
  margin: auto;
}
.sort .sort-icon.sort-asc {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.sort .sort-icon .sort-desc {
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.checkbox-wrapper-class {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  line-height: 21px;
}
  .checkbox-wrapper-class > label {
  bottom: 16px;
}
.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.row {
  outline: none;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.cell-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the `overflow: scroll;` on the wrong element. You need to remove `overflow-x: auto;` and `overflow-y: hidden;` from .list-container. You also need to remove `height: 300px;`, `overflow-y: scroll;` and `overflow-x: hidden;`. Once you do that you can just add `overflow: scroll;` to .table-container and then the horizontal scroll be fixed to the bottom and the vertical scroll be fixed to the right.

```css
.query-grid-container {
  height: calc(100% - 160px);
  margin: 48px 68px 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 136px);
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.loader-container {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.search-table-container {
  height: 100%;
}

.table-container {
  height: calc(100% - 72px); 
  overflow: scroll;
}

.top-container {
  padding: 14px 30px 15px;
  background: color("white");
}

.result-title {
  color: color("blue", 80);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.result-sub-title {
  color: color("gray", 60);
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.no-result-title {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.no-result-container {
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  padding-top: 24px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: color("white");
}

.no-result-text {
  margin-top: 6px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.no-result-top-container {
  border-bottom: 1px solid color("gray", 10);
  padding: 14px 30px;
  background: color("white");
}

.name-header {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.query-description-container {
  margin: 10px 0 14px 0;
  padding-left: 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
}

.cell-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: normal;
  padding: 6px 0 10px 10px;
}

.table-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  background-color: color('white');
}

.header-cell {
  border-top: 1px solid color("grey", 10);
  border-bottom: 2px solid color("grey", 10);
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.cell-wrapper {
  padding: 15px 0 9px;
  line-height: 24px;
  display: flex;
}

.checkbox-wrapper {
  margin-left: 38px;
  display: flex;
}

.column-name {
  color: color("blue", 80);
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: auto 6px auto 0;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

.sort {
  display: flex;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 0 0 0 2px;
}
.sort.sort-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sort.sort-btn:hover {
  background-color: color("gray", 10, 0.2);
}
.sort .sort-icon {
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
  margin: auto;
}
.sort .sort-icon.sort-asc {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.sort .sort-icon .sort-desc {
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.checkbox-wrapper-class {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  line-height: 21px;
}
.checkbox-wrapper-class > label {
  bottom: 16px;
}
.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.row {
  outline: none;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.cell-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>testtt</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<body>

 <div class="query-grid-container">
<div class="table-container">
    <div class="list-container">
      <div style="width: 2000px; height: 50px;">
        <div class="header-cell" style="width: 250px;">
          <div class="cell-wrapper">
            <div class="sort" role="Button" tabindex="0">
              <span class="column-name">Detected Data Classification Type</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-cell" style="width: 250px;">
          <div class="cell-wrapper">
            <div class="sort" role="Button" tabindex="0">
              <span class="column-name">Asset Name</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-cell" style="width: 250px;">
          <div class="cell-wrapper">
            <div class="sort" role="Button" tabindex="0">
              <span class="column-name">Selected Data Classifications</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-cell" style="width: 250px;">
          <div class="cell-wrapper">
            <div class="sort" role="Button" tabindex="0">
              <span class="column-name">Detected Data Classifications</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-cell" style="width: 250px;">
          <div class="cell-wrapper">
            <div class="sort" role="Button" tabindex="0">
              <span class="column-name">Short Description</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-cell" style="width: 250px;">
          <div class="cell-wrapper">
            <div class="sort" role="Button" tabindex="0">
              <span class="column-name">someTitle0</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-cell" style="width: 250px;">
          <div class="cell-wrapper">
            <div class="sort" role="Button" tabindex="0">
              <span class="column-name">someTitle1</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-cell" style="width: 250px;">
          <div class="cell-wrapper">
            <div class="sort" role="Button" tabindex="0">
              <span class="column-name">someTitle2</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="rows-container" style="width: 2000px;">
        <div class="row" tabindex="0" role="row">
          <div class="cell-group">
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[Inferred]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">
                <div>
                  <a href="#">Account Number</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">
                <div>
                  <a href="#">ACCOUNT_ID</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[ACCOUNT_ID, ACCOUNT_ID]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">A value representing an Account Number.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" tabindex="0" role="row">
          <div class="cell-group">
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">
                <div>
                  <a href="#">Address Line 3</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">Address Line 3 of a multi-line address.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" tabindex="0" role="row">
          <div class="cell-group">
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">
                <div>
                  <a href="#">Address Line 1</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">Address Line 1 of a multi-line address.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" tabindex="0" role="row">
          <div class="cell-group">
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">
                <div>
                  <a href="#">Address Line 2</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">Address Line 2 of a multi-line address.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" tabindex="0" role="row">
          <div class="cell-group">
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">
                <div>
                  <a href="#">Airport Code</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">A string representing the IATA airport code.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" tabindex="0" role="row">
          <div class="cell-group">
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">
                <div>
                  <a href="#">Alabama State Driver's License</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">A string representing driver license of US state Alabama.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" tabindex="0" role="row">
          <div class="cell-group">
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">
                <div>
                  <a href="#">Alaska State Driver's License</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">A seven digits number representing driver license of US state Alaska.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" tabindex="0" role="row">
          <div class="cell-group">
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">
                <div>
                  <a href="#">Alberta Province Driver's License</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">A string representing driver license of Canadian province Alberta.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" tabindex="0" role="row">
          <div class="cell-group">
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">
                <div>
                  <a href="#">American Express Card</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">A 16-18 character number that identifies an American Express credit card account.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" tabindex="0" role="row">
          <div class="cell-group">
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">
                <div>
                  <a href="#">Arizona State Driver's License</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">A string representing driver license of US state Arizona.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" style="width: 250px;">
              <div class="cell-wrapper">[]</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in this case, the header is not fixed at the top. Header has to be static. Only the body should be scrollable.

Comment: Okay check it again, I just removed overflow: scroll; from the header div.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the change , looks like the header is still scrolling.

Comment: Unless I'm not understanding what you're asking. The only one I can see you getting the header not to scroll is to move it outside of the .list-container div. When you set overflow to hide or scroll it is on the specific div. If you move the header outside of the div you set the overflow on it will not be hidden, and if it is hidden it will only be visible upon scrolling. I don't see the point of having a table if the content can be scrolled so it doesn't align with the column header.

Comment: I want the table to be scrollable exactly like this : http://jsfiddle.net/X2Kmd/1734/

Comment: That's how that code makes the table look. Run the code snippet, click full page and then resize the window to test accurately.

Comment: No. In your code, the header is also moving along with the rows, header shouldn't move.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166277/discussion-between-superuser-and-parrigin777).

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the inline style `overflow: scroll` below the div `list-container`,
2. Remove the css style `overflow-y:hidden` for `.list-container`
3. Remove the `overflow-y: scroll` for `.rows-container`!!

This works as expected!!

Comment: Thanks for the response. Vertical scrollbar is still not visible until the horizontal scrollbar is scrolled till the end. Can you please copy and edit the code I've added in the question.